# Cannot add multiple single images at once

Tags: ajax, uploads, media

I've stucked in a weird moment. When I am uploading multiple media (images) as spearate images in a post (so no gallery included; only single images; lets say about 10) nothing happened. When I'm checking the console, this is following error:

```
> POST http://grymuza.pl/v2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 404 (Not Found)
> load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery…:4
```

Strange things:
- file admin-ajax.php is uploaded/exists
- disabling all plugins change nothing / same issue
- changing theme do not influence on the issue.

sometimes in console appears also this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: FYI, I was just able to load the ajax url with no 404 error.

Comment: and that's weird. It pops-up only while adding multiple photos.